# Realm Database File Path Access in different name and by other application

Tags: database, realm

1st question: Can I rename my filename to a different file name? like "securedfile.realm"? Because I have it with default.realm

2nd question: Let's say I named my dbrealm with "securedfile.realm" from App1. What if I also named my dbrealm in App2 with "securedfile.realm". Will they access only 1 file? is it shareable?

I have my code here for the dbPath.

```
public class RealmDBAccessVariable
{
    public static readonly string dbPath = 
        Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "default.realm");
    public static readonly RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration(dbPath, true);
}
```

and usage here

```
    #region Insert City
    /// <summary>
    /// Insert City To Realm Local Database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="CityObject">CityObject _object</param>
    public void insertCityToDatabase(CityObject _object)
    {
        try
        {
            realm = Realm.GetInstance(RealmDBAccessVariable.config);

            using (var transaction = realm.BeginWrite())
            {
                var realmObject = realm.CreateObject<RealmObject>();

                realmObject.cityID = _object.cityID;
                realmObject.cityDescription = _object.cityDescription;
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            realm.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
    #endregion
```

Thanks for the answers in advance :)
If there are things that I made wrong in my coding, feel free to comment for improvement too :) I'm still exploring with realm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1.

You can use any file name by setting [name](https://realm.io/docs/java/3.0.0/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#name-java.lang.String-) in your configuration. If you need to rename the file, all Realm instances must be closed (not doing that, the behaviour is undefined and it might lead to crashes).

ad 2.

Currently, Realm for Android does not multiprocess access. Only one process at the time can access. We have an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1091) about it.